# importing tflearn - No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.framework'

Tags: python, tflearn

then i type **import tflearn** i got the error below, i follow the guide here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViO56ASqeks

what can i use tflearn, or shall i use another code?

i got the error below.

```
import tflearn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tflearn/config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .variables import variable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tflearn/variables.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.framework
```

can someone help me ?

**20/08-2019: Edit 20.35**
pip list:

> tensorflow 2.0.0rc0

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by:-
1) upgrading python to 3.6
2) pip uninstall tflearn
3) pip install git+https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn.git
4) As suggested in another solution tensorflow 2.0.0 does not support tflearn so I installed tensorflow==1.14.0

I found the solution here:-
[Issue Link/](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/787)

Comment: i was looking for solution from 5+ hours still not getting but finally i got the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an conda environment (and not only, but I advise you to use it), then the solution will be to use a lower version of tensorflow `pip uninstall tensorflow` `pip install tensorflow==1.14.0`.

And it is possible to use the script to fix all errors(i used it before downgrade tf):

```
tf_upgrade_v2 \
  --intree my_project/ \
  --outtree my_project_v2/ \
  --reportfile report.txt
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to have tensorflow installed before you can use tflearn.
From the [tflearn](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn#installation) github page:

> TensorFlow Installation
>   TFLearn requires Tensorflow (version 1.0+) to be installed.

To install tensorflow:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial that you are watching uses tensorflow version 0.9 or something, current version is 2.0. The tutorial is ***3 years*** old. You should watch updated video.

However, you can try.

```
pip install tensorflow==1.0
pip install tflearn
```

> if you're using a virtual environment, make sure you have activated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keras` instead of `tflearn`.

`tensorflow.contrib` is being removed in version 2.0, you therefore need version <= 1.14 to operate tflearn ([see here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30794#issuecomment-512188521)).